# How to find the triple-wise intersection count of all three vector subets of a set of vectors?

Tags: pandas, set, data-science

I'm trying to find intersection of A, B, C for all possible A,B,C column  vectors in the following df.
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ytCE.png)

`print(df)`

```
   0  1  2  3
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  0  1  1
2  1  0  1  1
3  0  1  0  0
4  1  0  1  0
```

`df.T.dot(df)`

gives pairwise intersection counts of column vectors

[dot product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lE98j.png)

```
   0  1  2  3
0  3  0  2  1
1  0  1  0  0
2  2  0  3  2
3  1  0  2  2
```

How do I get to intersection triples among column vectors
Eg: col 0, col 2, col 3 has value 1*1*1 = 1.

I'm trying to make a three dimensional association matrix for item-item-item similarity. What is the best approach here?

Comment: I see you have your dataframe alread in jupyter notebook. Could you do `print(df)` and paste that output in your question. We cannot copy pictures.

Comment: 0  1  2  3
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  0  1  1
2  1  0  1  1
3  0  1  0  0
4  1  0  1  0

Comment: I cant seem to paste the matrix here. I used ```df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(5, 4)))``` to create the random matrix

Comment: What would your expected output be? Could you add that as well

Comment: A 4*4*4 cube matrix dont know how to represent it. Shall I do it in four slices?